Rotate encryption key for asm tde wallet oracle 19c
I have 1 database that has the tde encryption wallet located in ASM rather than o/s
I now need to rotate the encryption key.  I normally do this by changing the key ob one node then copying to the wallet location of all the other nodes. I can’t find any clear instructions on what to do when the wallet in is ASM as the asmcmd commands do not work on a wallet. Has anyone done this and could you share the method
